# How do you keep your phone vibrating indefinitely?

Tags: vibration

I'm suspecting that the vibrator in my phone is not working properly. Before opening the case, I'd like to diagnose first. I need to make my phone keep vibrating for a while, say, like 2 minutes or more. I haven't found any good solution other than calling this phone with another.

I'd like to keep it vibrating without generating other sound, e.g. ringtone when someone calls you.

Comment: I would suggest something along the lines of beeshyams' answer, you could also try "Automate" if "Macrodroid" isn't to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a one-time test, I suggest a simple macro using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid).

Use **+** to add Trigger/actions from the corresponding panel

**Trigger:** Empty Trigger

**Actions**

1. Conditions/Loops → Repeat actions → Fixed number → OK → Fixed count say 70
2. Tap on End Loop → Add action above → (Device Actions → Vibrate → Long buzz) → OK
3. Tap on End Loop again to add one more action of wait 1 second (MacroDroid Specific → Wait Before Next Action)

From the Overflow menu, choose "Test actions" and your phone should buzz *almost* continuously for long enough (increase the count in step 1 if required)

Comment: In step 3 you can increase to 2 seconds - some devices don't work with short intervals of one sec

Comment: @AndrewT, thanks for updating! Appreciate much :)